# How can I create Drupal Commerce product collections?

Tags: drupal, commerce

How can I group products in collections?

For example:

Manufacturer Collection1 {Product1, Product2}
             Collection2 {Product3, Product4}

Collections are contain parameters: size, wight, width ant etc.
Products are contain only individual parameters: color, name.

How I can create this structure?
How I can create product page with Collection parameters display as separate fields.
How can I search collections in views and search products?
How can I open collection with all products of this collection?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about bulk product creation:

https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_bpc

Also, check this article:

https://drupalcommerce.org/discussions/1722/how-does-commerce-bulk-product-creation-work

Comment: Thank you, MilanG! I have created taxonomy collections vocabulary with fields as parameters. Thus the parameters of the collection I bring once. But facets cant filter products by taxonomy fields (inside taxonomy reference field) Can you help me?

Comment: Sorry, what "facets" are?

Comment: Facet filters (Search API)